No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Int32' a tipo 'System.String'
Estoy trabajando en un formulario en asp.net MVC con c# y al guardar me aparece el error "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'" al guardar la informacion en la base de datos. La conexion se realiza correctamente. Dejo el codigo del controlador del get y del post
public async Task<IActionResult> Crear()
{
        
    var viewModel = new DropdownListViewVeterinario
    {
        SelectDocumentos = await ObtenerListaDocumento()
    };
    
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Crear(DropdownListViewVeterinario veterinario)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        veterinario.SelectDocumentos = await ObtenerListaDocumento();
        return View(veterinario);
    }
  
    await repositorio.SaveVeterinario(veterinario);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> ObtenerListaDocumento()
{
    var queDocumento = await repositorio.ObtenerTipoDocumento();
    return queDocumento.Select(x => new SelectListItem(x.Documento, x.idTipoDoc.ToString()));
}

Realice pruebas de guardado quitanto la lista desplegable de la base de datos y del codigo y guarda la informacion sin problemas, y esto me demuestra que la funcion guardar funciona correctamnete. Pero al agregar la listadesplegable de nuevo vota el error, en el modelo se declara todo correctamente, en la vista se muestra la lista desplegable. Tambien dejo la funcion de guardado
public async Task SaveVeterinario(Veterinario veterinario)
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        var id = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<int>(@"insert into Veterinario (Nombre,Apellido,idTipoDoc,NumDoc,codVet,PasswordHash,Veterinaria,Telefono,Email,fechaRegistro,fechaModificacion,EstadoRegistro)
                                                values (@Nombre,@Apellido,@idTipoDoc,@NumDoc,@codVet,@PasswordHash,@Veterinaria,@Telefono,@Email,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),1);
                                                SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", veterinario);
        veterinario.idVeterinario = id;
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}


El error te da en la función ObtenerListaDocumento?

por las pruebas que realice, es al momento de guardar el valor de la lista desplegable. Si empleo el Devtools del navegador, captura la id de la lista desplegable, pero al momento de apretar el boton guardar me envia el error

Tengo una duda en esta parte de tu código: var id = await connection.QuerySingleAsync. Seguro que es int lo que va entre las flechitas, segun yo ahi debe de ir el nombre del objecto, en este caso Veterinario

Lo pude resolver quitando el atributo StringLength al numero telefonico que es un int
